# Mergin /adding fields inside of a CSV using NiFi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi, batch-processing

i got following task/problem:

I got a static data file, that file is pushed into a bigquery table. When pushed, the flowfile gets handed further. before the file is pushed again into another bq table BUT several field got some kind of Logic to be processed before the file is pushed into the second bq table.

example:
There are 2 Fields in the input file which should be merged into one field before pushed into bq.
-> concrete: content of Field GD270A and GD270B should be put together (strings, both)and put into GD260

The Pipeline work as far as the first push but im missing the merging logic, is there any default processor or do i need to develop a custom one?

current Set-up is a GCP (1 VM running NiFi, 2 Buckets and a BQ)
The NiFi-pipe looks like this:
[The NiFi-pipe looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbUWF.png)

Any help or Idea is very much appreciated!

Edit:

Header of the CSV:
GD622|GD622PW|KZLOESCH|KZLOEDAT|GD100A|GD270A|GD270B|GD260|GD240|GD245|GD621|GD170|GD171|GD172|GD198A|GD198B|GD198C|GD198D|GD198E|GD198F|GD198G|GD455A|GD630A|GD455D|GD660|GD669|GD867A|GD205C|GD161|GD432|GD432A|GD649|FTRELEV|FTGUEAB|FTGUEBIS|GD968D|GD160|GD650A|GD630B|GD226|CUSIPNR|GD200|GD211|GD212|GD213|GD214|GD220|GD220A|GD221|GD225|GD228|GD230|GD258U|GD280A|GD290A|GD300|GD311A|GD311B|GD312|GD321|GD322|GD352|GD352A|GD400|GD481|GD545|GD636|GD685G|GD685H|GD801A|GD801AJN|GD802|GD802A|GD803E|GD804E|GD805|GD806|GD806A|GD808|GD808A|GD808B|GD808C|GD809A|GD811|GD815B|GD815C|GD821B|GD861A|GD861E|GD861F|GD862|GD910|GD910A|GD924|GD924B|GD970A|GD970I

one example line:
||1||1|**VALL**|**oN**||EUR|STK|EUR|U202|ZZZZ|ZZZZ|+000000000000000001.000000000||||||K6431|AD||||||||043|||50||+00028|4|956|36||+129|043||B|0916|SH|||||13|||||||049||7||N||||||||||||||||||||||||||

In Bold are the field which should be merged into GD260 as following:

||1||1|VALL|oN|**VALLoN**|EUR|STK|EUR|U202|ZZZZ|ZZZZ|+000000000000000001.000000000||||||K6431|AD||||||||043|||50||+00028|4|956|36||+129|043||B|0916|SH|||||13|||||||049||7||N||||||||||||||||||||||||||

hope this helps, "|" obviously is the delimiter :)

Comment: can you provide a sanitised example of the data?

Comment: I would highly advise you to use the [Nifi mailing lists](https://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) or the [Slack Channel](https://apachenifi.slack.com/) to get help with NiFi.

Comment: @Squashman thx - will look into that

Comment: @Sdairs
maybe not the best example but, see edit of original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should be able to do this with a single [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) - see the [Additional Details](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html) page for examples

Using `Replacement Value Strategy` of `Record Path Value` - see the docs for how to use [Record Paths](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html)

Adding a user-defined Property to the `Update Record` with name `/GD260` and a value of `concat(/GD270A, /GD270B)` - using the [concat function](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#concat)

Comment: It actually did concat the field which i needed but i might need to change the csv layout/format or the table... i might come back tomorrow, till then - thanks very much :)